# Nuxt 3 + content module: querying content by locare broke default routing

Tags: vuejs3, nuxtjs3, nuxt-i18n, nuxt-content

I'm having trouble setting up a multilingual site with the `@nuxt/content` module in Nuxt 3. I thought I had correctly configured the query for the `ContentDoc` component, but now the fallback routing from `/` to `/index.md` is not working anymore.

This is my `pages/[...slug].vue` file:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <pre>
    current locale: {{ locale }} 
    current pathWithoutLocale: {{ pathWithoutLocale }}
    </pre>
    <ContentDoc
      :query="{ path: pathWithoutLocale, where: { _locale: locale } }"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { useI18n, useRoute } from '@nuxtjs/composition-api';
const { locale } = useI18n();
const { path } = useRoute();
const pathWithoutLocale = path.replace(`/${locale.value}`, '/');
</script>
```

In my `content/it` and `content/en` folders, I have an `index.md` file and a `foo.md` file. However, when I navigate to `/`, I see the content of `foo.md` instead of `index.md`, which should be the default fallback for the routing.

What am I doing wrong?

([issue reproduced on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-jnysug))

Comment: I encountered the same problem. I'm pretty sure it is a bug. Github issue: https://github.com/nuxt/content/issues/2115

Comment: I have thought about it, and indeed, by introducing a query as a criterion for extracting content, it might make sense for the automatic extraction of indexes to be eliminated and for the first returned result to be the first in alphabetical order.

The solution I was adopting was to name the index with a leading 0. However, I encountered other issues while trying to build a functional skeleton that met our requirements, so for now, we are working with another framework.